# Сразу закрывается Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

При вызове `dialog` появляется окно и сразу закрывается, вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы не закрывалось?

```
var date=$('input[type="text"]');
$('form').find('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function (){

    if (date.val()==""){
        alert('Строка пустая')
    }
    else {
         $( function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog();

        } );

    }

})
```

Comment: Происходит отправка формы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 3):

Вы не прерываете текущее действие submit.

```
var date=$('input[type="text"]');
$('form').find('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function (){

    if (date.val()==""){
        alert('Строка пустая')
    }
    else {
         $( function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog();

        } );

    }
    return false;
})
```